# How to append data to the list on each button click : Angular typescript + Laravel

Tags: angular, laravel, typescript

I have a system like shown below, When ever I type reference ID it generates a record corresponding to that by taking that record from the DB.

[image]

My issue here is, Whenever I type a new reference number and add, it just overrides the existing record, but what i want is when ever I add a new one, that new record to get added to the list.

**html code**

```
<div *ngIf="show">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-12">

            <label class="col-sm-12 cm">Details</label>

            <table class="table table-hover">
                <tr>
                    <th>Reference ID</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Surname</th>
                    <th>Reference </th>
                </tr>

                    <td>{{Details.id}}</td> 
                    <td>{{Details.firstname}}</td>
                    <td>{{Details.lastname}}</td>
                    <td>{{Details.reference}}</td>

            </table>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**typescript**

```
add() {
    const data = {
      reference: this.assistant.reference,
    }
    console.log(data);
    this.Service.add(data)
    .subscribe(
      req => {
        console.log("successful");
        this.show = true;
        this.Details.id = req['data']['member_record']['id'];
        this.Details.firstname = req['data']['member_record']['first_name'];
        this.Details.lastname = req['data']['member_record']['last_name'];
        this.Details.reference = req['data']['member_record']['reference'];
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      }

    );
  }
```

Can anybody help to append records one by one with the button click theres a separate back end to it where all the models, controllers, services are written accordingly.

P.S : and furthermore it would be really helpful if some could give me a tip on how to delete those records(after I put the button as the next step) not from the db but from the ones that appear in the UI.

Comment: can anybody help me out on this? :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer,

In your .html

```
<table>
    <th>
      <td>Reference ID</td>
      <td>First Name</td>
      <td>Surname</td>
      <td>Reference</td>
    </th>
    <tr *ngFor="let detail of details">
      <td>{{detail.id}}</td>
      <td>{{detail.firstName}}</td>
      <td>{{detail.surName}}</td>
      <td>{{detail.reference}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

in detail.model.ts

```
export class Detail {
  id : number;
  firstName : string;
  surName : string;
  reference : string;
}
```

In your .ts

```
details : Detail[] = [];
```

So in your add button there is function call add() and its implementation should be like this,

```
add(){
   detail = getRecordFromDb(); //get the generated record from table.
   this.details.push(detail); // push above line generated record in to details array.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another workaround for adding items to already existing list.

```
this.details=([... this.details,...detail])
```

Here, details is the list in which we can add items repetitively and detail is the new model which we can get every time. so details will be appended with new data every time without overwriting.